# How does the inject method work?

Tags: ruby

I am a beginner in Ruby and I came across a code snippet which had the following:

```
def add(*nums)
  nums.inject(&:+)
end
```

Examples:

```
add(1, 2)
#=> 3
add(1, 2, 3, 4)
#=> 10
```

How does the code snippet work?

Comment: have you tried reading the documentaiton on `inject`?

Comment: Thank you, @SergioTulentsev.I was a bit confused with the document at the beginning.Now the code snippet makes sense to me.

Comment: This is a pure-Ruby question so it should not have a Rails tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As specified in the doc: https://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/inject

`inject`:

> Combines all elements of enum by applying a binary operation,
>   specified by a block or a symbol that names a method or operator.

You can use it with `enumerable(array, range, ..)` like this,

```
[1, 2, 3].inject { |sum, number| sum + number }
```

or short-hand style,

```
[1, 2, 3].inject(&:+)
```

If you're wondering about this `(&:+)` and how it works, check this also,

[What do you call the &: operator in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2259775/what-do-you-call-the-operator-in-ruby)

Comment: That is normally written `[1, 2, 3].inject(:+)`. Extra credit for explaining the difference between using `&:+` and `:+` as `inject`'s argument. Also, [Enumerable#sum](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-sum) made its debut in Ruby v2.4, allowing one to write `[1, 2, 3].sum #= > 6`.

Answer (score 1):

In the docs it says it works like:

```
# Same using a block and inject
(5..10).inject { |sum, n| sum + n } #=> 45
```

https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-inject

Eg. It is summing up 1,2,3,4 which equals 10

Answer (score 1):

As I have done so in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46306458/5101493), print each step using `puts` to see what's going on:

```
def add(*nums)
  nums.inject { |sum, element|
    puts "",
         "sum is #{sum} and element is #{element}",
         "new sum is #{sum} + #{element} = #{sum + element}",
         "-" * 25
    sum + element
  }
end

add(1, 2, 3, 4)
#sum is 1 and element is 2
#new sum is 1 + 2 = 3
#-------------------------

#sum is 3 and element is 3
#new sum is 3 + 3 = 6
#-------------------------

#sum is 6 and element is 4
#new sum is 6 + 4 = 10
#-------------------------
#=> 10
```